# NSDateFormatter giving the wrong Hour (+8 hours)

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I don't undersatnd why I get 8:00AM instead of 00. This also happens if I set it to other hours.

[image]

Ok, I now tryed to present in a label the value of

```
[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTest];
```

And in a wierd way it presented the time I formatted... But if I check the NSDate object on a breakpoint then it says 08:00:00 and not 00:00:00;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess that you live in the States, which uses GMT -8 time zone at the date specified (maybe PST?). So the date has been parse correctly already, because it said it was GMT.

Comment: I don't live in the states but I have a mac from the US that is still running with american clock.

But see what I added to my question, can you explain it?

Comment: It's because it displays the date in the machine time zone.

Comment: I changed the time zone on the machine and now it really shows the gour +- the time zone.

The reason I got confused is that for time 00:00:00: it presented 8:00:00 and US is GMT-8 not +8.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The dateFormat string is wrong. It should be

```
"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
```

See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

The main problems are

- `DD` is the day of year, not day of month. So 07 will override the month "November" set previously.
- `hh` can only recognize numbers in the range [1, 12], which 0 is out of range.

Comment: @Gal: Is `date1` really already initialized? Try to check the value only when the control reaches the line at `NSDate* date2 = ...`.

Comment: Ofcourse... I'm an experience programmer, I know how to debug code.

Thanks :)