# NSDateFormatter is shifting the date of 2 hours, why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I want to convert the following `NSString` to a `NSDate` : `@"2013-04-01T22:00:00Z"`

I am using the following code :

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-04-01T22:00:00Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *theDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

When I print `theDate` I get the following answer : 2013-04-01 20:00:00 +0000

Now I am wondering why the hour is 20:00 instead of 22:00, do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This must be one of the most often duplicated questions in the iOS / cocoa tags. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Nsdateformatter+wrong+hour did you search first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter giving the wrong Hour (+8 hours)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117515/nsdateformatter-giving-the-wrong-hour-8-hours)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong time from NSDateFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466419/wrong-time-from-nsdateformatter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since your dateFormat does not specify a time zone the `NSDateFormatter` uses your local timezone. You have to set the timezone yourself. The Z in your string means GMT.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Timezone in your code, i have tried in your default TImeZone. its working fine.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-04-01T22:00:00Z";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    NSDate *theDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: Tried this line also
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

Comment: This code is wrong. Do not quote the `Z` in the date format. And there is no reason to set the timezone to the default timezone, that is already the default.